# What is the next term of this sequence?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

What is the next number?

$$2,3,10,12,13,20,?$$

Comment: Please cite the source of this puzzle. (A quick Google search shows this isn't your own puzzle)

Comment: @Greg well, it was a math teacher I had 5 years ago that told me, I picked it up from there... do I need to cite him as a source?

Comment: Ahh, in that case, I would say no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is:

> 21

because

> the list is all numbers whose name begins with 't'

Comment: dang it, that was quick! Adapted it from my language, where the sequence would be:

$$2,10,12,16,17,18,19,200$$